# Rename a field in access vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to rename a field name in VBA access code to automate things so it works faster. I am using a button to move some data around and need to change the column names, as a result, to clean things up. I am working out of a form but the table I need to change isn't linked to the form at all...

I have tried using some VBA code but keep getting variables undefined errors like the tblFieldBookwslk50 is not defined

```
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("tblFieldBookwslk50", dbOpenDynaset)
'rename field names
rst.TableDefs(tblFieldBookwslk50).Fields("GDU_slk_50_Daily HU").Name = 
"GDU_slk50"
rst.TableDefs(tblFieldBookwslk50).Fields("tblFieldBookwshd50_Daily HU").Name = "GDU_shd50"
db.Close
rst.Close
```

I want the field names to say 'GDU_shd50' rather than it say 'tblFieldBookwshd50_Daily HU'.

Comment: I don't understand need to program this. Open table in design view and modify. Don't use a recordset object to change table structure, use a tableDefs object. Consider: `CurrentDb().TableDefs(TableName).Fields("OldName").Name = "NewName"`

Comment: A recordset doesn't have tabledefs, the database has. You aren't quoting `tblFieldBookwslk50` which means it's a variable, but you haven't defined it. Also, you don't want to open up a recordset at all when renaming a field, just the tabledef.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the `TableDefs` in the `Database` object.

```
Set db = CurrentDb
'rename field names
db.TableDefs("tblFieldBookwslk50").Fields("GDU_slk_50_Daily HU").Name = "GDU_slk50"
db.TableDefs("tblFieldBookwslk50").Fields("tblFieldBookwshd50_Daily HU").Name = "GDU_shd50"
db.Close
```

Comment: I keep getting an run-time error saying Cannot define field more than once

Comment: Does the field name you are trying to change it to currently exist in that table?

Comment: Yes it does, I included those in a previous step

Comment: A field name must be unique. If it already exists, you'll have to rename it to something else. If the field already exists, why are you trying to rename another field to that name?