# Rename columns in MS Access using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

In MS Access, I have a few tables with some column names having spaces in their column names (e.g. `Transaction I`).

I need to replace the spaces with underscores (e.g. `Transaction_ID`) using SQL.

Although I'm somewhat familiar with SQL, however, my exposure was in an Oracle environment and all of those queries and functions don't work in MS Access. I am fairly new to MS Access.

I have tried following codes from the posts that I searched, however, to no avail.

```sql
alter table EP sp_rename 'Transaction ID' to Transaction_ID
alter table EP rename column 'Transaction ID' to Transaction_ID
```

Comment: Are the tables local Microsoft Access tables, oder e.g. linked SQL Server tables?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename a field in access vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57616034/rename-a-field-in-access-vba)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access does not have a built in command "line" option to re-name a column.

(and your example looks to be for SQL Server, and MORE so it looks to be using a library stored procedure function to do this for you. So, that looks to be SQL Server syntax - not MS Access.

If you going to use DDL in Access to re-name a column? You have to create a new column with the desired name, and then move the data to this new column, and then drop the old column.

The so called sql 'ddl' commands in Access actually do quite much follow the SQL standard.

So, before embarking on this road, I would consider to use the built in GUI + table designer. (It will do the dirty work behind the scenes for you).

So, can you use DDL to rename a column? Yes, but you have to do this in 3 steps.

Create the new column.

Copy data from old column to new column

Delete the old column.

Because of indexing, possible relationships and other issues, then one REALLY does want to use the built in table designer + the GUI here.

But, you can use say a procedure (VBA) in Access to do this:

Say we had a REALLY bad column name for City called [The City].

To re-name to City, then we can go:

```
Sub MyAlter()

  ' create the new column
  CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE tblHotels ADD COLUMN City TEXT(50)", dbFailOnError

  ' copy the data
  CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblHotels SET City = [The City]", dbFailOnError

  ' drop the origonal column

  CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE tblHotels DROP COLUMN [The City]", dbFailOnError

End Sub
```

Just keep in mind that ANY column in Access with spaces (yuk!!) needs to be surrounded with []. This applies to SQL select queries, update queries, insert queries, and of course DDL commands to modify the table structure.

If a one-time deal, then of course simply use access, open the table(s) in question in design mode, and make the changes.

However, if you do for some reason do need to use a procedure, then the above code in a access code module can be used.

Or you could just fire up the query builder, flip to SQL view mode, and type in the above raw sql that way.

(you have to type in each sql command separately - the Access query builder only allows ONE SQL statement at a time.

So you could type in first above SQL, hit "!" to execute, and then do the two additional SQL statements.

MAKE A BACK-UP!!!

And of course any code, any queries, any reports etc. that used the old column name will break. So changing column names in an existing application is a HIGH RISK adventure (you can and will break tons of code, existing forms, and existing reports, and existing SQL queries you have now).

However, if this is a one-time update? Then I would of course just use the table designer. It allows a re-name without a column drop – and it keeps other field settings such as indexes, format etc.

I which above suggested approach makes the most sense will depend on your particular "use" case.

Last but not least? You can use VBA code and the table objects in that code. This approach is probably the best. It does not use SQL DDL, and you have greater control over a lot of features for a given column (required, allow nulls – the list goes on). Most of these settings CAN be set in DDL - but you spend quite a bit of time searching and looking up those settings.

All in all? I would use the table designer if possible here.